# WP migration failed, now it won't output anything

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I messed up a wp installation so I decided to backup the database and re-install, then I deleted all the wp database tables and imported my backup

Now It doesn't output even errors ( http://toniweb.us/codigo/ ), even that I changed the debug option into true:

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Any idea what could I try now to find out where the error comes from?

-EDIT-

Also tried:

`ini_set('error_reporting', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Try running it via the command line (`php ./index.php` from the wordpress root). You're going to get some unrelated noise _from_ running it in the console, but you'll also see errors that might not have made it to the browser that probably should have. Got to love 'white screens of death' :) If you get something odd, update your question, might be able to zero in on it from that.

Comment: The problem is that this is a shared hosting and there's no access by ssh.. any alternative? @TimPost

Comment: Bugger - no, other than pulling down your files and DB and trying to reproduce it locally. That stinks, because console debugging can make short work of things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Can you log in to the admin area? I just tried to visit your admin login screen and got presented with the 'Wordpress needs to update the database' message, this is common after failed upgrades/migrations, usually hitting the update button will fix your issues (*update*: in this case it appears to have done so).

2/ Try switching to the default Wordpress theme (rename your current theme via FTP if you can't access the admin area). If you can access the admin area then try to reset your permalinks (just select the same option you have now, it will update it in the database).

3/ Failing that, check your themes `functions.php` file for any white space at the end of the document, this sometimes produces a blank white screen instead of your site.

Comment: I guess you or someoneelse clicked the button, cause first I say it was the login page!